# jQuery ui autocomplete not firing select event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, asp.net-web-api2

I have a jQuery autocomplete, and the `select` event is never fired.

The script looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#AppName').autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function(request, response) {
            var url = "/api/AddAppAjax";
            $.getJSON(url, { term: request.term }, function(data) {
                response(data);
            })
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            alert(ui.item.id); <---- !This is never hit!
            $('#selected-id').val(ui.item.id);
        }
    });
})
```

The Web API controller action looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<object> Get(string term)
{
   var appManager = new AppManager();
   var appList = appManager.GetAllApps().AsQueryable().ToList();
   var appListJson = from fbApp in appList
   select new
   {
      id = App.Id,
      value = App.AppName,
      label = App.ToString()
   };

   return appListJson;
}
```

The autocomplete itself works fine. It's just the event that isn't firing. I tried binding to the event with `bind` and `on` and that didn't help either. I also tried this on the `change` event, and that does not get fired either, or so it looks to me. I can't figure out why the event is not firing.

Comment: Could it be the jQuery 1.9.1 issue? Here's the [link to the issue](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/autocomplete-click-to-select-item-not-working-in-1-9-1)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention... I am using jQuery 2.1.1 and jQuery ui 1.10.4

Answer (score 3):

I think so you need to add this too...

```
$( "#AppName" ).on( "autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

[You can check it out here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select)

Comment: I was using an ancient version of jQuery and so used bind() instead of on()

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The problem for me was that a secondary autocomplete targeted the same element.

In your case it could be that ('something').autocomplete() also hits the #AppName element.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like, you have to return response from source function

```
$(function() {
    $('#AppName').autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function(request, response) {
            var url = "/api/AddAppAjax";
            $.getJSON(url, { term: request.term }, function(data) {
               return response(data);
            })
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            alert(ui.item.id); <---- !This is never hit!
            $('#selected-id').val(ui.item.id);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: I didn't see this in the official jQuery ui examples, but tried it and it still does not work.